# How can I remove > symbol in MGWT CellList

Tags: mgwt, celllist

I need to show dynamic list using a cell list. But the condition is to remove the > symbol by overriding its CSS. Is it possible to override its css to reach my goal or is it impossible. If possible tell me the approach.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, is possible to remove the ">" symbol.

If you take a look into the code this arrow is generated with this css:

```
.mgwt-List-group {
    background-image: arrowImage;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 100% 50%;
}
```

So, you have some paths to follow:

1. Generate your own style and leave blank this css class.
2. In your code override the "`background-image`" for each element li. Using something
   like: `background-image: none !important;`

Anyway I am going to create a patch for this class about this problem. Probably something like setGroup(boolean showArrow); and in the constructor as well.

UPDATE: There is a method called **setGroup(boolean group)** yet that can solve the problem! I did not see when I wrote this answer. You can use it!

Comment: setGroup() is working but what if you want only some cells to be a group with an arrow and some not?

Comment: In that case maybe the fastest way is to override the backgorund-image property. How to do this? I would use GQuery with css selectors, something like $(#idOfCellListElement, yourCellList).css("...",".."); of course you can elaborate more the query. Happy coding!